# Regarding single column or composite primary key

Tags: postgresql

Is it better to have a single column primary key, or use composite primary keys . I have examples below:

```
 create table emp(
 subsidiary_id  smallint   , 
 Employee_id    int        ,
 emp_name       varchar,
 constraint emp_pkey primary key ( subsidiary_id   , Employee_id     )
```

Data will be line

```
 subsidiary_id , employee_id
    1,                 1
    1,                 2
    1,                 3
    2,                 4 
    3,                 5
    2,                 6
```

employee id cannot be same for any subsidiary , always unique but on my reports using both the column in where clause as subsdiary_id = 1 and employee_id = 1 or and so on

so want to know to better approach to create primary on employee_id column or both which one is better?

Comment: Your code is incorrect, you can only specify `primary key` once. You need `primary key (subsidiary_id, employee_id)` at the end of the table definition.

Comment: There is no absolute "the better" solution for anything. Why not create an `id serial`?

Comment: A composite primary key would make good sense if you plan on running queries which could make use of indices on both columns.

Comment: A composite PK only makes sense if the combination of `subsidiary_id` and `employee_id` are not supposed to ever repeat.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : yes, i know code is incorrect , this is just information to have primary key on both columns.

Comment: @Jim Jones  employee_id will never repeat for any subsdiary_id , some reports having where clause with subsdiary_id only so there is any impact ?

Comment: a PK will control the data integrity. So if you do not want that the combination of `subsidiary_id` and `empolyee_id` ever repeat, it's indeed wise to have a composite PK. Regarding queries it is another issue about the most appropriate index. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-multicolumn.html - if you will perform queries using only one column, it probably makes sense to have an extra index only for this specific column, regardless of the composite PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a composite primary key is the right solution for you:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
   subsidiary_id  smallint  NOT NULL, 
   employee_id    int       NOT NULL,
   emp_name       text,
   CONSTRAINT emp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (subsidiary_id, employee_id)
);
```

The index that is created for this constraint will also be useful for queries where only `subsidiary_id` appears in the `WHERE` condition.